# drop shadow for menu header in css

Tags: html, css, adobe, dropshadow

I have a [menu header](https://postimg.org/image/ifvv3ootv/). The drop shadow effects of it as present in the adobe photoshop are:

```
Blend Mode: Multiply
Opacity: 0.25 (25%)
Distance: 3px
Spread: 15%
Size: 9px
Color: #282829
```

I am trying to use the above code in my CSS for my menu header (adove) but unfortunately for some reasons I am unable to replicate it. The code which I am using for the menu header are:

```
    position: relative;
    top: -890px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 89px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #EF7440;
    overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: @MichaelCoker   `position: relative;
    top: -890px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 89px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #EF7440;
    overflow: hidden;`

Comment: @MichaelCoker Is there any problem with the `background color`? I just put it there randomly to match the image but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I think there is some confusion. I am trying to replicate the the image which I have posted. The code which I have used in order to replicate the image is: `position: relative; top: -890px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); height: 89px; border-bottom: 3px solid #EF7440; overflow: hidden;` but unfortunately for some reasons, it is not working. I haven't mention the text part of the code which I believe is not necessary in order to replicate an image.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and adjust the pixel values if necessary. The 4th value is the blur size, the 3rd value is the size of the spread. The 1st and 2nd values adjust the X and Y offsets of the dropshadow.

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 3px rgba(41,41,41,.25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 3px rgba(41,41,41,.25);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 3px rgba(41,41,41,.25);
```

Comment: Only the last one is getting selected. The above 2 ones (`-webkit` and `-moz`) are not working.

Comment: They are just prefix options. -webkit is Safari and Chrome. -moz is Mozilla. Your Browser will use the property name that it recognizes and ignore the others. It should only be using one at a time - but you need to make sure to match the values on all 3 so that is renders the same in all browsers.